# Replace admin header logo with an image

Tags: functions, hooks, actions

I want to replace the default WordPress admin bar logo to my custom logo which is a PNG file. I have tried a code it's not working.

```
function custom_logo_admin_header() {
echo '
<style type="text/css">
#wp-admin-bar-wp-logo > .ab-item .ab-icon { 
background-image: url(' . get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/images/wp-logo.png)   !important; 
background-position: 0 0;
}
#wpadminbar #wp-admin-bar-wp-logo.hover > .ab-item .ab-icon {
background-position: 0 0;
}   
</style>
';
}

add_action('admin_bar_menu', 'custom_logo_admin_header');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the path to the image is wrong, use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` to retrieve the `style.css` path. If this isn't it let me know and I will take a closer look.

I just dug out an example which worked for me in the past:

```
function my_login_logo() { ?>
 <style type="text/css">
    body.login div#login h1 a {
        background-image: url(PATH_TO_FILE);
    }
</style>
<?php }
```

---

Update: I really should read more carefully before replying! Ok how about this ->

```
function custom_logo_admin_header() { ?>
    <style type="text/css">
      #wp-admin-bar-wp-logo > .ab-item .ab-icon { 
          background-image: url(<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/wp-logo.png)   !important; 
          background-position: 0 0;
      }
      #wpadminbar #wp-admin-bar-wp-logo.hover > .ab-item .ab-icon {
        background-position: 0 0;
      }   
    </style>
<?php
}
```

---

New Update: This one is as well locally tested!

All above are off track and this will lead to the best result.

```
function no_wp_logo_admin_bar_remove() {        
    ?>
        <style type="text/css">
            #wpadminbar #wp-admin-bar-wp-logo > .ab-item .ab-icon:before {
                content: url(<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/wp-logo.png)   !important;
                top: 2px;
            }

            #wpadminbar #wp-admin-bar-wp-logo > a.ab-item {
                pointer-events: none;
                cursor: default;
            }   
        </style>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'no_wp_logo_admin_bar_remove', 0);
```

Now about there where to put this, you can add it in the functions.php and you can put it in the plugins main .php file, which as well will do the trick. Let me know if this worked.

Comment: Changed Like this `background-image: url(' . get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/wp-logo.png) !important;` the default logo got removed.but it is not loading the new one.

Comment: bro I am asking about the admin-bar logo not login page logo

Comment: Will this work if use this code in plugin? or I have to put the code in function.php?

Comment: bro I have small doubt, What's that the 0 means in `add_action`

Comment: That's the priority of the call, default is 10, 0 is pretty high, before everything else to precise.

Comment: Thanks ! bro Is there any way to remove the link from the logo?

Comment: I looked around and didn't find anything too helpful. If you wanted to remove the image AND the link this could help `function remove_admin_bar_link() { global $wp_admin_bar; $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('wp-logo'); } add_action( 'wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'remove_admin_bar_link' );`

Comment: No the logo is must :(

Comment: I have added to the last version a CSS update which does not remove the link, but makes it unclickable and the cursor does not change. Is that sufficient?